# Find the determinant, assuming that

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & f &  g\\ 
q & w & e 
\end{vmatrix} =5$$

It is a whole matrix above.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & f &  g\\ 
q+d & w+f & e+g 
\end{vmatrix}=?$$

It is a whole matrix above, too

---

I know the answer is 5, but I don't know how to find that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & f &  g\\ 
q & w & e 
\end{vmatrix} =5$$

We know that,

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & f &  g\\ 
q+d & w+f & e+g 
\end{vmatrix} = (q+d)\begin{vmatrix}
b & c \\ 
f & g 
\end{vmatrix}-(w+f)\begin{vmatrix}
a & c\\ 
d & g 
\end{vmatrix}+(e+g)\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\ 
d & f 
\end{vmatrix}$$

which equals to:

$$5+d(bg-cf)-f(ag-dc)+g(af-bd)=$$

$$=5+dbg-dcf-fag+fdc+gaf-gbd=$$

$$=5$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Take line 3 subtract line 2 and for on line 3 (Determinant is not change)

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & f &  g\\ 
q+d & w+f & e+g 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & f &  g\\ 
q& w & e 
\end{vmatrix}=5$$

Answer (score 2):

The new matrix has the same determinant as the old one, since from old to new, the second row is added to the third row.

From the properties of determinant:

> Adding a multiple of a row (column) doesn't to another doesn't change
>   the determinant.

For your interest, see [properties and proofs](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant).

Comment: Thank you.  This does help.